# Error starting docker daemon

Tags: docker, boot2docker, dockerfile, dockerhub

```
root@default:/# docker images
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker -d' running on this host?
root@default:/# docker -d
Warning: '-d' is deprecated, it will be removed soon. See usage.
WARN[0000] please use 'docker daemon' instead.
INFO[0000] Listening for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock)
INFO[0000] [graphdriver] using prior storage driver "aufs"
INFO[0000] Option DefaultDriver: bridge
INFO[0000] Option DefaultNetwork: bridge
FATA[0000] **Error starting daemon: Insertion failed because database is full: database or disk is full**
```

---

> ****FATA[0000] **Error starting daemon: Insertion failed because database is full: database or disk is full******

---

I understand that it is a space issue, but I cannot delete docker images or docker non-running containers as docker service is not running.

I am facing the issue in boot2docker.What is the way to clear spaces when docker service is not running.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to restart the daemon ? `sudo service docker restart`

Comment: By the way, there is no service command available in boot2docker .. sudo service docker restart
sudo: service: command not found

Answer (score 0):

Probably your boot2docker vm is full. You can check it getting into your boot2docker vm with:

```
boot2docker ssh
```

then you run this one to see storage status:

```
df -h
```

If it is really full you can resize your VM size ou remove something. The docker files are stored at `/var/lib/docker` there you can find folders with your volumes, containers, diffs, aufs storage, etc.

By the way I suggest you upgrade from boot2docker to Docker Toolbox. You can even migrate your boot2docker vm.